# need to create a .pem file

Tags: python

What the `.pem` file contain? simply a key or a function which generate the key.

I need to create a `.pem` file and also need to call this file in a function.

here is code to which I have to proceed:

```
pk = open( 'public_key.pem', 'rb' ).read()
rsa = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key(pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to create a pem file.  You will need to supply it the correct parameters to get the correct type of key.  The [genkey](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genpkey.html#) command of openssl looks like what you want to use.

Comment: And if you are using it you should know about the keystore to set it for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to create a public key pair, then save them unencrypted to two files.

```
    from M2Crypto import RSA
    key=RSA.gen_key(2048, 65537)
    key.save_pem('./privkey',cipher=None)
    key.save_pub_key('./pubkey')
```

To read it, do:

```
rsa=RSA.load_pub_key('./pubkey')
```

And similar if you want to load the private key as well. Good luck!